# Getting the product of all elements in a certain column

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Say you have a 3x3 matrix that ressemble this:

```
R={{R1, R2, R3},{R4, R5, R6},{R7, R8, R9}}
```

I want to get the product of the first row, therefore, R1*R4*R7.

I used the function `Times @@ R[[All, 1]]` **but was wondering if there is another way, perhaps a more efficient one.**

Comment: Could you expand on what you find unsatisfactory in the method you proposed? It seems pretty direct.

Comment: Well, I was trying to use the function Product[] but couldn't make it work..

Comment: @alex_t then how about `Product[R[[i, 1]], {i, 1, 3}]`?

Comment: Note, `Product` is more intended for symbolic products (like `Sum` is for addition), so `Times` will almost guaranteed be faster for preconstructed lists/matrices, especially if they are numeric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is quite efficient, especially when compared to using `Product`:

```
data = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {1000, 1000}];

Product[data[[i, 1]], {i, 1, Length[data]}]; // RepeatedTiming
(* Out: {0.470, Null} *)

Times @@ data[[All, 1]]; // RepeatedTiming
(* Out: {0.00015, Null} *)
```